# Get index of sorted row?

Tags: javascript, sorting, datatables, html-table

In the context of [DataTables](https://datatables.net/), how do I get the index of a sorted row?

I have a paginated, sortable, filterable table where column `4` (i.e. the 5th column) contains a message number. I'm writing a function which switches the current page to the one displaying that message number, and highlights the row containing that entry. It looks like this:

```
var currentHighlight = null;

function goToMessageNumber(number) {
  var table = $('#messages').DataTable();

  // remove current highlight
  if (currentHighlight) {
    $(table.row(currentHighlight).nodes()).removeClass('highlight');
  }

  // find the row we need
  var index = table.column(4).data().indexOf(''+number);
  if (index === -1) {
    return;
  }

  currentHighlight = index;

  // add new highlight
  $(table.row(currentHighlight).nodes()).addClass('highlight');

  // go to page
  var page = Math.floor(currentHighlight / table.page.len());
  table.page(page).draw(false);
}
```

It works perfectly if the table is in the initial sort order. However, this fails when filters or sorting is applied. What's the easy solution here?

Comment: If you mean a  `<tr>` element, you can always get the index with the `.rowIndex` property. Or are you asking about something specific to a library?

Comment: @squint: Yeah it's specific to [DataTables](https://datatables.net/).

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over `every()` row in the current `{ search:  'applied' }` order, by that calculate the current page where the value you are looking for is present. Here is an illustrative example looking for a certain name :

```
$('#goto').on('click', function() {
  var page, data, count = 0;
  table.rows( { search: 'applied' } ).every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
    count ++
    data = this.data()
    if (data[1] == 'Airi Satou') {
      page = Math.floor(count / table.page.len())
      table.page( page ).draw('page')
      return
    }
  })
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/1o3fLcqy/**

The above jumps to the page where `Airi Satou` is located, regardless of sorting / filtering (assumed `Airi Satou` is present in the current rows). Do the same with your message numbers in column #5.

---

Regarding manipulating the row / `<tr>`, `rowIdx` holds the original index. So you can do this  :

```
table.row(rowIdx).nodes().to$().addClass('highlight')
```